# How to convert '10-Mar-1993' to date while inserting records in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have written the following query:

INSERT INTO programs
(programId,programName,startDate,annualGoal)
VALUES
(135,'Community Evergreening',STR_TO_DATE('10-Mar-2013','dd-mmm-yyyy'),25000);

But, it says "Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '10-Mar-2013' for function str_to_date".

I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: There is a manual for this kind of thing

Comment: I know Sir.
I tried searching online as well. I was able to convert "Mar 10, 2013" to date. I was able to convert many other formats to date. But, I am getting an error for specifically this error.

Comment: Looking at [the manual for STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) shows the format of the format string.

Comment: @danblack Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to represent the date format like this: `%d-%b-$Y`

```
STR_TO_DATE('10-Mar-2013', '%d-%b-%Y')
```

The problem is that you are using the format `dd-mmm-yyyy`. However, MySQL's date formatting does not use that format.

If you look at the documentation for [str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), it says that it is the inverse of date_format, and that you can look at the [documentation for date_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for a table of the characters that you can use to represent a date format.

> For the specifiers that can be used in format, see the [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function description.

Answer (score 0):

Try `STR_TO_DATE('10-Mar-2013', '%d %b %Y')`

Got from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp)

Comment: Close! Don't forget that the OP's date was formatted with dashes between the date parts.

Comment: It's too late to be doing this! :)